# How to write about ordered things?

Tags: vocabulary, numbers, ordinals

Can anyone help me about the correct usage of nd and th ?

> The n**th** best grade
>   The n'**th** best grade
>   The n**nd** best grade

---

What are they called in the grammar ?
Which one of them is grammatically correct ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: *'th* ("apostrophe th") is never correct in ordinal numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are called **ordinal numbers.**

The first three always have the -st, -nd & -rd ending:

> 1<sup>st</sup>, 2<sup>nd</sup> & 3<sup>rd</sup>.
>   In the same fashion, 21<sup>st</sup> = twenty-first, 22<sup>nd</sup> = twenty-second, 23<sup>rd</sup> = twenty-third, and so on.

For upcoming numbers add -th:

> 4<sup>th</sup>, 7<sup>th</sup>, 14<sup>th</sup>...

As for the spelling, add -th.

> *fourth, seventh, fourteenth.*

If the number is a multiple of 10, the spelling changes:

> 30<sup>th</sup> = ***thirtieth***.

Comment: Should I necessarily put the **th** in the form of superscript ?

Comment: To answer @Cardinal's question, no, the superscript is not necessary. "4th" is perfectly fine.