# i-th vs. iᵗʰ vs. ith

Tags: word-choice, numbers

I wonder which form(s) are correct amongst the following:

- This is the **i-th** item in the sequence.
- This is the **ith** item in the sequence.
- This is the **i<sup>th</sup>** item in the sequence.

---

Example:

From Finlayson, Bruce A. [Numerical methods for problems with moving fronts.](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZRXjkEjKxb0C&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=%22i-th+element%22&source=bl&ots=3PrjtPxs2N&sig=1ALYDyk4g-UGlQk7a7gviCYgEWI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-lN2LzobKAhVDHh4KHXRnB2AQ6AEIWTAN#v=onepage&q=%22i-th%20element%22&f=false) Bruce Alan Finlayson, 1992.

[image]

---

A related discussion on LaTeX Stack Exchange: [1st, 2nd and i-th?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10959/11400)

Comment: I've never seen the first one but I've seen plenty of the other two.

Comment: ([Allow sub- and superscripts in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136553/178179))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write about ordered things?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74752/how-to-write-about-ordered-things)

Comment: @Catija Thanks, any idea regarding `i-th`?

Comment: J.R. is correct... it's not something I've ever seen. If you can come up with a legitimate example of it, I'd be interested to see it.

Comment: @Catija Sure, added in the question. (In French, my mother tongue, I always use the third form.)

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. This looks like a special case because "ith" would look odd in writing... so to specifically clarify and make it obvious that it's a variable, the hyphen is used - "i-th" But, in general, I do not believe this form would be used. The more common use for an undefined term is "nth"... which won't be confused with anything else, generally.

Comment: @Catija Thanks, is there any reason why `nth` would be preferable over `iᵗʰ`?

Comment: This is not a "right or wrong" question, it's more of a "style preferences" question.

Comment: That may be a better question for math or TeX. I believe "n" generally refers to whole, positive integers... and "i" can potentially be conflated with imaginary numbers.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks. Since it sounds like none of the three forms are against some English rule, I'm trying to weight the pros and cons for the readers. I find  `iᵗʰ` easier to parse. But perhaps one might argue that using superscripts look messy versus staying at the same level. Other ideas of potentially subjective elements to take into account are welcome.

Comment: @Catija *n* is usually used for natural numbers (i.e., nonnegative integers) while *i* is a more general indexing variable (it could range over all real numbers in an interval, for example). The context makes it clear that *i* does not refer to the imaginary unit in this case.

Comment: @Catija Also, *n* is already used for something else as anyway in the text I am writing :)

Comment: I suppose that if you italicize "ith" instead of superscripting it, that might make it more obvious and look less like a typographical error.

Comment: @Catija Good point. Now that you mention it I recall having read i*th* in quite a few places.

Comment: Here's a related question on ELU: [Do I write p-th or pth?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/273803/77227)

Comment: what about i+1-th

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem occurs because some display devices do not support **superscripting** (9<sup>th</sup>) or **multiple fonts** (9 *th*).  From my experience:

When the ***th*** is **preceeded by a numeric**, there is no problem

> **4th**
>   **120th**

this form is often used in addresses in the US.

For a **number as text** the ***th*** is considered part of the text

> **fourth**
>   **ninth**
>   **eighth**

When a **counting variable** is used, a "**-**"(hyphen) can be added for clarity

> **i-th**
>   **j-th**
>   **n-th**

[ Note: *i* and *j* are used in **standard mathematical matrix notation** ]

When a **specific iteration** is referenced, a hyphen is also used

> **9-th**
>   **20-th**

to maintain conformity.

[ Note: this is different than the first example ]

Comment: Can you offer a citation for your claim that a hyphen is *usually* used? My personal experience with textbooks and academic papers (for mathematics specifically) is that a hyphen is not common.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no firmly established standard for writing this kind of "numbering". Best practices are determined by the common usage within the relevant field (e.g. math, physics). Mathematical notation (which this is) is always a matter of convention and can vary even between subfields.

The third option is by far the clearest in the case of the given example, but I can also imagine *ith* being acceptable. *nth* is common enough not to require the superscript. You might want to use the hyphen for, e.g., variables that already have subscripts and/or superscripts. The example of *i-th* you gave looks unusual to me, but the fact that it exists in a recent publication suggests that it is also at least somewhat acceptable.